# Wait for onclick event to complete before jquery event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tagging system for countries. There is an input by which user can perform a query, query results are displayed as a dropdown box and once one of the results is clicked, query is reset and country name is "appended" to the input.

This system looks much like Stackoverflow's question tagging system. I've done all those steps except for one, which is to close the menu when the input is unfocused (this basically means that every click outside of the input should close the query menu).

Code below is responsible for adding all the countries to the query menu, notice the **tagItem.onclick** event definition, once the tag is clicked it is "appended" to the input.

```
$.each(data.countries, function(i, item) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var tagItem = document.createElement("span");
    tagItem.innerHTML = item;
    tagItem.onclick = function() { add_tag(item); };
    tagItem.style.cursor = "pointer";
    tagItem.className = "reg_c_interest_tag";
    listItem.appendChild(tagItem);
    document.getElementById("reg_c_interest_queryresult").appendChild(listItem);
});
```

To capture the click events outside of input, I figured that the neatest option would be `$(selector).focusout` event:

```
$("#reg_c_interest_editor").focusout(function () {
    $("#reg_c_interest_queryresult").empty();
});
```

## The problem

Unfortunately, these two events interfere with each other, `focusout` event is registered quicker than `onclick` event, thus before user clicks on any tag `focusout` function empties the menu.

I know I should be using Jquery's `$(selector).click` but I'm not sure how could that be done in the iteration process.

How can I prioritize these `onclick` events? so that `focusout` function is only executed once `onclick` is.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe try `.blur` instead of `.focusout`? `.blur` supports event bubbling

Comment: That is normal event flow. In order to click on something the other element loses focus first. Provide a [mcve]. You probably want to place event listener on document instead and check target inside it

Comment: And for tagging purpose, you can try using Jquery plugin: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html

Comment: @Sagivb.g Unfortunately `.blur` doesn't work ether..

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I was thinking of that solution for while. And it worked, thanks!